# Is FlushFileBuffers required to sync file data across many processes?

Tags: windows, winapi, io

I have a file which is read/write by many processes, they use a mutex to serialize the read/writes.

Is it required that I call `FlushFileBuffers` after `WriteFile` in `ProcessA` so that `ProcessB` would see these changes? Or would `ProcessB` be guaranteed to see the changes that `ProcessA` made, assuming the OS disk cache for this file is shared between all processes? After calling `WriteFile` I do not call `CloseHandle` on the file, I leave it open in all processes but they have the `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` flags passed to `CreateFile`.

This is required to work across Windows XP to Windows 8.1 - I've found that calling `FlushFileBuffers` presents an unacceptable performance bottleneck.

Comment: This doesn't sound like the best IPC mechanism. Perhaps you might consider something other than a disk file for your IPC.

Comment: DavidHeffernan I agree but as this point it can't be changed so I have to make the best of a bad situation. @HanPassant is there any docs that show this to be true? Everything in the docs of CreateFile etc seem to suggest they may not see it.

Comment: Not necessary, other processes also read from the file system cache.  A program can intentionally use FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING in the CreateFile() call to bypass the cache.  It gets what it deserves, very slow reads and no visibility to writes that haven't been flushed.

Comment: So FlushFileBuffers is required if FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING is not passed to CreateFile?

Comment: You'll need to assume that the programmer is not a fool.

Comment: Well I'm confused, it appears that FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING or FlushFileBuffers in place of have the same effect, yet you say none of these are required to guarantee file consistency across process A and B which both have it open as they share the OS cache. Yet MSDN has no mention of this :)

Comment: I believe you'll find that in practice and under normal circumstances all processes do in fact share a single cache and that it will work without flushing the buffers but AFAIK this is not guaranteed.  The documentation does appear to guarantee coherency if you share a single file object (e.g., by duplicating handles between the processes) but this comes with its own set of caveats (though it should work OK if you use only asynchronous I/O).

Comment: @Hans: You're confusing the issue... with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, there's no such thing as a write that hasn't been flushed.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I believe his point is that a program using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` might read old information from the disk when there is newer information in the cache (written by another program that does *not* use the flag).

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The other program would have to be doing memory-mapped I/O for there to be a difference.  Another program using `WriteFile` either has called `FlushFileBuffers`, in which case its writes are visible both in cache and on disk, or it hasn't, in which case its writes are in per-process buffers, not even in the shared cache yet.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm not sure there are any per-process buffers; do you have a reference?  The documentation makes it fairly clear that once the write has completed, the data is in the system cache, under the control of the cache manager.  It does not explicitly guarantee that the cache manager will maintain coherency between processes (i.e., will not have the same file or part thereof cached more than once) but in practice that seems to be the case.  The docs certainly don't guarantee that two processes *won't* share the same cache, so at the very least there *might* be a difference.

Comment: There is one relevant sentence: "Caching is managed per file object."  This *could* mean that each file object has a logically distinct cache, or it could mean that each file object either is or is not cached; I'm not sure which was intended.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The documentation is found in the comments for [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "With one important exception, file views derived from any file mapping object that is backed by the same file are coherent or identical at a specific time. Coherency is guaranteed for views within a process and for views that are mapped by different processes. The exception is related to remote files." ... "A mapped file and a file that is accessed by using (ReadFile and WriteFile) are not necessarily coherent."

Comment: Anything beyond that is implementation details and cannot be relied on.  It might be different among Windows versions, or even different filesystems or storage stacks within the same version.

Comment: @BenVoigt: that says that the cache manager and the memory manager don't maintain a single mutually coherent view, it doesn't really say anything (either way) about per-process caches.  But in the absence of any documentation about the contract for the cache manager, it would be unwise to depend on the observed behaviour, so I agree with your posted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes which have a memory-mapped view of the file have direct access to the page in the disk cache; accesses are coherent with all other processes on the same machine, and your mutex is sufficient for synchronization.

Processes which use file access APIs need to call `FlushFileBuffers` to ensure coherency.

If you can't get away from shared files for IPC (for example, you can't change one of the participants), you can at least migrate the ones you do control to memory-mapped file views, for a big performance benefit.